# Removing an element from a library

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, scripting

I have a library in a list which contains a document I want to delete. This has to be done for site collections, so I decided to make a script do it.

```
#Set the Error Action

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

Try{
    $customers = $SiteURL.GetFolder
    foreach ($customer in $customers){
        #customer is a list that contains the library sitepages
        $customerlists = $customer.List.TryGetList("Site Pages")
        #correctitem is the document item that I want to remove
        $correctitem = $customerlists.List.TryGetList("123")
        if ($correctitem){
        #delete it (havent gotten here yet)
        }
        }
        }
catch {
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
}
finally {
    #Reset the Error Action to Default
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
}
```

However, I cant get it to work. The URL works, but the customers variable, when I try to Write-Host it does not display anything. 
Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is `$SiteURL`?  Presumably it's something in the `Microsoft.SharePoint` namespace, but I have no idea what object might have a `GetFolder` property.

Comment: @BaconBits SiteURL is the url for the sharepoint site I am using to start searching from. I tried GetFolder (because it would work if I searched once and not in a loop), but also tried getting all the Lists on the URL, but that too would not give me output if I tried Write-Host. I am new to Powershell so sorry if its not a good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a document from a document library, the PowerShell script below for your reference:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://sharepoint-site-url")
$web = $site.openweb()
$list=$web.Lists["Site Pages"]
$listItems = $list.Items
$listItemsTotal = $listItems.Count
Write-Host $listItemsTotal
for ($x=$listItemsTotal-1;$x -ge 0; $x--)
{
  if($listItems[$x].name.Contains("123")) # file refers to the name of the document
  {
    Write-Host("DELETED: " + $listItems[$x].name)
    $listItems[$x].Delete()
  }
}
```